# Scheme - Can a Double-Quote Delimit a Number?

Tags: parsing, lisp, scheme, implementation, interpreter

I'm currently implementing a web-based Scheme environment for the kicks and giggles. Whilst implementing the parser, I stumbled across an oddity: some Scheme implementations state that a number's digits are read until a delimiter is met, but they also claim a double-quote is a valid delimiter. Successfully evaluating `123"abc"` seems odd to me, but Racket seems to do it, displaying `123` and `"abc"` sequentially.

Confused, I booted up Gimp and went into it's Script-Fu console, which is Guile Scheme underneath. Giving it the same expression, it complains about an unbound value; so it's trying to parse it as a symbol?

I tried out JScheme as a 'third opinion'. It also complained about an undefined variable.

**TL;DR:** What should Scheme's behaviour be here?

Side-note: given the latter two's complaints, I tried the following:

```
(define 123"abc" 10)
123"abc"
```

It evaluated as `10`. I'm confused. Shouldn't the double-quotes mark cause the parser to bail out rather than assign the symbol?

Comment: For reference the syntax of Scheme is described in R5RS or R6RS. I would expect that 123"abc" gets parsed into a number and a string. But best consult the respective implementation maintainers. It's best answered by them. The question is interesting, but it's likely that you would get answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your chosen Scheme implementation (you may need to load in [SRFI 6](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-6/srfi-6.html) before string ports will work):

```
(call-with-input-string "(123\"abc\")" read)
```

On both Racket and Guile, this reads in as `(123 "abc")`, which is exactly as I expect. From a quick glance at R5RS's "Lexical structure" section, I believe that implementations that return something different, like `(|123"abc"|)`, are probably non-conformant.